# installing Google Client Library for Google Analtics PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api-php-client

first of all I am new to this topic, so I hope my question is not too stupid.

I want my website to have PHP access to Google Analytics metrics. I followed every step of this [description from google](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php). Unfortunately when I upload everything on my server and try to run the test-site, I always get the following error-message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library
>   must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See
>   the instructions at
>   https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in
>   /home/users/myftp/dev.mywebsite.com/dashboard/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php:14
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/users/myftp/dev.mywebsite.com/dashboard/HelloAnalytics.php(8):
>   require_once() #1
>   /home/users/myftp/dev.mywebsite.com/dashboard/HelloAnalytics.php(104):
>   getService() #2 {main} thrown in
>   /home/users/myftp/dev.mywebsite.com/dashboard/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php
>   on line 14

So apparently there is something wrong with the embedding of the Google client library. In the error message it says I have to use Composer, but in the GitHub documentation they say, manual download would be fine as well. I think in the end this shouldn't make any difference? I am not familiar with composer or GitHub, this is why i downloaded it manually.

I uploaded it on the server and put it into the same directory like the HelloAnalytics.php. I address it in HelloAnalytics.php via

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/autoload.php'
```

Comment: You really need to get acquainted with composer. This is must have part of modern php development workflow.

Answer (score 6):

From the looks of it you are using the wrong autoloader.

`src/Google/autoload.php` looks for the composer autoloader and if it doesn't exist it throws the exception you are getting.  Since you didn't install using Composer it is not found and that exception is thrown.

If you clone the repository using git you will have the correct SPL autoloader.  If you download the package it uses the composer autoloader.

Try downloading using:

```
git clone -b v1-master https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git
```

Or switch to the v1-master branch and use [this](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/v1-master/src/Google/autoload.php) autoloader instead.  You will see that file differs between the `master` branch and the `v1-master` branch.

Comment: Yes the document has been updated to reflect the correct branch: `git clone -b v1-master https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git` In the future the php library will only support composer, but that branch is not yet stable. For the time being stick with branch tag v1-master

Comment: Thank you for the answer. i was not aware, that I used the wrong autoloader. I watched a few tutorials about composer and was able to install the library correctly.

Comment: @AndréGC and please share us those tutorials, or write a new tutorial and teach us.

Answer (score 5):

to avoid AUTOLOADer error,  install MASTER-V1 version:
[**https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master**](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/tree/v1-master)

p.s. if you will get other error, then ensure that you have correctly included the "SERVICE EMAIL" (that is like: `xxxxxx@analytics-xxxxx.iam.gserviceaccount.com` ).

Comment: @T.Touda Where service email is written ? where we should add uit?

Comment: @HamzaZafeer i dont remember, just read that github page for examples & details.