# Google API:Looking for the code of php classes needed for spredsheet API google installation or to work (cli not allowed)

Tags: php, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-sheets-api

i looked at the Github downloaded php code for "happy shit" (:p) or API sheet,
but the code example seems strange.
I'm used to such curl classes and JSON opening, on Facebook and Twitter, but I really don't understand here

I don't have CLI access on the server, and can't install by this way. And the code downloaded doesn't/can't work.

So i looked at the example code given on documentation and github#installation:

require_once '/path/to/your-project/vendor/autoload.php';
=>Ok, but the code doesn't declare any classes.

#

code php

```
/**
 * THIS FILE IS FOR BACKWARDS COMPATIBILITY ONLY
 *
 * If you were not already including this file in your project, please ignore it
 */

$file = __DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php';

if (!file_exists($file)) {
  $exception = 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package.';
  $exception .= ' See the instructions at https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.';
  throw new Exception($exception);
}

$error = 'google-api-php-client\'s autoloader was moved to vendor/autoload.php in 2.0.0. This ';
$error .= 'redirect will be removed in 2.1. Please adjust your code to use the new location.';
trigger_error($error, E_USER_DEPRECATED);

require_once $file;
```

So, how can the Basic Example work, please?
-https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation

```
`// include your composer dependencies
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("YOUR_APP_KEY");

$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);

foreach ($results as $item) {
  echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
}
```

#

I looked in the client.php file, but it call on undeclared classes without any require...

So my question is how to start in php?
(I understand credentials and the ID needed, getting the Access_token,... But how to require/declare the classes?)

My downloaded src copy :https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_hTHU7PDrJpX0ttWjd3RmtLZkU/view?usp=sharing

Thanks (it's for work...)

###############

---

Answer to comments from Dalm:

developers.../sheets/api/quickstart/php that's the page I come from.
and the code came from the github link given

Step 1: Turn on the Google Sheets API=OK 
Step 2: Install the Google Client Library=how to run php in cli if no cli?
Step 3: of course give:

quicstart.php:

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'This library must be installed via composer or by downloading the full package. See the instructions at github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation.' in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\leviet\pourFred\Google\autoload.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\leviet\quickstart2.php(2): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\leviet\pourFred\Google\autoload.php on line 14

---

So I tried the exec commands:

```
$output2 = shell_exec('php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0');
$o= exec('php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0',$output,$return);

print_r('output2:'.$output2);
print_r('o:'.$o);
passthru($o);
print_r('output:'.$output);
print_r('return:'.$return);
```

which give as a result:

```
output0:
o:
output    
return:1
```

---

I also tried the exemple from the github:
github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/examples/simple-file-upload.php

```
<?php
/*
 * Copyright 2011 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
include_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';
include_once "templates/base.php";
echo pageHeader("File Upload - Uploading a simple file");
/*************************************************
 * Ensure you've downloaded your oauth credentials
 ************************************************/
if (!$oauth_credentials = getOAuthCredentialsFile()) {
  echo missingOAuth2CredentialsWarning();
  return;
}
/************************************************
 * The redirect URI is to the current page, e.g:
 * http://localhost:8080/simple-file-upload.php
 ************************************************/
$redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($oauth_credentials);
$client->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);
$client->addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive");
$service = new Google_Service_Drive($client);
// add "?logout" to the URL to remove a token from the session
if (isset($_REQUEST['logout'])) {
  unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
}
/************************************************
 * If we have a code back from the OAuth 2.0 flow,
 * we need to exchange that with the
 * Google_Client::fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode()
 * function. We store the resultant access token
 * bundle in the session, and redirect to ourself.
 ************************************************/
if (isset($_GET['code'])) {
  $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
  $client->setAccessToken($token);
  // store in the session also
  $_SESSION['upload_token'] = $token;
  // redirect back to the example
  header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
// set the access token as part of the client
if (!empty($_SESSION['upload_token'])) {
  $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    unset($_SESSION['upload_token']);
  }
} else {
  $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
}
/************************************************
 * If we're signed in then lets try to upload our
 * file. For larger files, see fileupload.php.
 ************************************************/
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && $client->getAccessToken()) {
  // We'll setup an empty 1MB file to upload.
  DEFINE("TESTFILE", 'testfile-small.txt');
  if (!file_exists(TESTFILE)) {
    $fh = fopen(TESTFILE, 'w');
    fseek($fh, 1024 * 1024);
    fwrite($fh, "!", 1);
    fclose($fh);
  }
  // This is uploading a file directly, with no metadata associated.
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $result = $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'media'
      )
  );
  // Now lets try and send the metadata as well using multipart!
  $file = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
  $file->setName("Hello World!");
  $result2 = $service->files->create(
      $file,
      array(
        'data' => file_get_contents(TESTFILE),
        'mimeType' => 'application/octet-stream',
        'uploadType' => 'multipart'
      )
  );
}
?>

<div class="box">
<?php if (isset($authUrl)): ?>
  <div class="request">
    <a class='login' href='<?= $authUrl ?>'>Connect Me!</a>
  </div>
<?php elseif($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'): ?>
  <div class="shortened">
    <p>Your call was successful! Check your drive for the following files:</p>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=<?= $result->id ?>" target="_blank"><?= $result->name ?></a></li>
      <li><a href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=<?= $result2->id ?>" target="_blank"><?= $result2->name ?></a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<?php else: ?>
  <form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" value="Click here to upload two small (1MB) test files" />
  </form>
<?php endif ?>
</div>

<?= pageFooter(__FILE__) ?>
```

But the **'template/base.php' doesn't exist** anywhere in the downloaded code...

**I found a problem about this last one:**
in the "master" download, only the "src" repertory is present.
And the template directory is normaly in the example repertory (only available in **versions: "fixes-1122" and "v1-master"**

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/php

Comment: Thanks Dalm, but that's the documentation I followed, and I block at the line:

php composer.phar require google/apiclient:^2.0

Step 1: Turn on the Google Sheets API=OK
Step 2: Install the Google Client Library=how to run php in cli if no cli?

Comment: I answered at the end of the initial question

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33570979/1841839

Answer (score 1):

So, I answered my quesion:

1.download the full github (with exemple and src repertory) on
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation
**but not** the google-api-php-client-master client

2.Create an api key

"enjoy"

ace of Ap(i)s: the origins !